# Proof of Gauss Seidel converges for any initial vector if the Coefficient matrix is diagonally dominant.

Tags: numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Friends

I came through the proof of [Gauss-Seidel method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method) I understood except the points marked in blue, and in the last line how the inequality is $<1$, it seems obvious but still it looks complex.

Source - Numerical methods for Scientific computation by S.K.Jain, [proof of Theorem 3.7](https://books.google.com/books?id=5XappvcENCMC&pg=PA162).

[image]

[image]

EDIT : Already figured out the last inequality but still trying to understand the WLOG part, any intuition on why we can assume $\|x\|_{\infty} = 1$?

Any help !

Comment: WLOG part is ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you already have the part about inequality.

> Without loss of generality, we assume that $\|x\|_{\infty} = 1$.

This is saying simply that you can rescale eigenvector.

All parts of the proof before this sentence work for any eigenvector $\mathbf x$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$. If $\mathbf x$ is an eigenvector, then so is $c\mathbf x$ for any non-zero scalar $c\ne0$. So we may simply take the eigenvector
$$\mathbf y=\frac{\mathbf x}{\|\mathbf x\|_\infty}.$$
The vector $\mathbf y$ is an eigenvector corresponding to the same eigenvalue $\lambda$. Moreover, this vector has the property $\|\mathbf y\|_\infty=1$. So we can work with this eigenvector in the rest of the proof.

Basically the whole sentence "Without loss of generality, we assume that $\|x\|_{\infty} = 1$" is saying what I wrote in the above paragraph and that in the rest of the proof we denote this eigenvector by $\mathbf x$ (and not by $\mathbf y$ in order to simplify notation.)

---

Just in case you are asking not *what is meant* by this sentence but you are asking *why* is this useful in the proof and how does it help: The answer is that it does not change that much. If you really want, you can try to do same proof with arbitrary non-zero eigenvector $\mathbf x$. (I.e., without the assumption $\|\mathbf x\|_\infty=1$.) Basically the changes in the proof will be that you choose $i$ as the index with maximal value of $|x_i|$ (instead of $|x_i|=1$) and you would use inequality $|x_j|\le|x_i|$ (instead of $|x_j|\le1$). You should be able to arrive to almost the same inequality, but each term is multiplied by $|x_i|$. 
$$|\lambda| \cdot |a_{ii}| \cdot |x_i| \le \sum\limits_{j=i+1}^n |a_{ij}| \cdot |x_i| + |\lambda| \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} |a_{ij}|\cdot |x_i|$$
Since $\mathbf x$ is non-zero and $|x_i|\ne0$, you can divide both sides of the inequality by $|x_i|$ and then continue precisely in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

I think that @MartinSleziak was already crystal clear but... The proof starts by taking an eigenvalue $\lambda$ and **one** of its eigenvectors. If $x$ is an eigenvector associated with $\lambda$, the same happens with any scalar multiple $k x, k \ne 0$. Since we get to choose $x$, we decide to choose it in such a way the largest component (in absolute value) is equal to 1.

Imagine that  $y = (1, 2, 3)$ is an eigenvector, then we can take $x = (\frac 13, \frac 23, 1)$ which is also an eigenvector and satisfies $\|x\|_{\infty} = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

For the inequality part

As we know that $A$ is a diagonally dominant matrix so ,from the definition of diagonally dominant matrix we can say that

for $i =1,2,...,n$

$|a_{ii}| > \sum_{j=1,j\neq i}^{n} |a_{ij}|$
       $ = \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} |a_{ij}| + \sum_{j=i+1}^{n} |a_{ij}| $

$|a_{ii}| - \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} |a_{ij}| > \sum_{j=i+1}^{n} |a_{ij}| $

that is $\frac{\sum_{j=i+1}^{n} |a_{ij}|}{|a_{ii}| - \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} |a_{ij}|} 
< 1$

But still trying to understand the WLOG part why such an assumption ,any intuition to it ?