# Convergence of Gauss-Seidel for a matrix where the transposed matrix is strictly diagonally dominant

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2161968/proof-of-gauss-seidel-converges-for-any-initial-vector-if-the-coefficient-matrix) post, it is shown that for a matrix $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$, the Gauss-Seidel iteration method for the solution of linear systems converges if $A$ is strictly diagonally dominant, i.e. if $$|a_{ii}|>\sum_{j=1\\j\neq i}^n|a_{ij}|$$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$. (One has to show that for $T:=-(D+L)^{-1} U$, given the splitting of $A$ in lower, diagonal, and upper triangular matrices, $A=L+D+U$, the spectral radius satisfies $\rho(T)<1$.)

A similar result is true if $A^\intercal$ is strictly diagonally dominant, i.e. if $$|a_{ii}|>\sum_{j=1\\j\neq i}^n|a_{ji}|$$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$. Is there any easy way to use the first result to derive the second?

Comment: your initial condition is reversed: If the matrix is strictly diagonally dominant, the method converges. Th condition is not necessary for convergence, only sufficient.

Comment: @PierreCarre Yes, but I want to show that if $A^\intercal$ is strictly diagonally dominant $\implies$ the method converges for $A$. (Given the theorem that if $A$ is strictly diagonally dominant, then the method converges for $A$.)

Comment: Keep in mind that this is an application of the fixed point method. Being diagonally dominant by lines or columns, means that the $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ or the $\|\cdot\|_1$ norms of the iteration matrix are less than one. (The convergence of the fixed point is guaranteed if some norm of the iteration matrix is less than one, hence the condition on the eigenvalues, that provide a lower bound for any matrix norm).

Comment: @PierreCarre Thanks! The problem I have is that I cannot derive this; I know that I somehow have to show that $\|T\|_1<1$, but the proof of $\|T\|_\infty<1$ in the first case is not directly applicable to the proof of $\|T\|_1<1$ (in the $A^\intercal$ case) which I am trying to write down, at least I don't see a direct way to prove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to apply the result that has already been established.

---

Let $A = M - N$ be the splitting of $A$ where $M = D + L$ is lower triangular and $N = -U$ is strictly upper triangular and let $G = M^{-1}N$ be the matrix driving the functional iteration 
$$
M x_{n+1} = Nx_n + f
$$
If $A$ is strictly diagonally dominant by rows, then we already know that the spectral radius of $G$ satisfies $\rho(G) < 1$. We will now assume that the matrix $A$ is strictly diagonally dominant by columns. We now define an auxiliary sequence $\{y_n\}$ by $$y_n = M x_n.$$ The sequence $\{x_n\}$ is convergent if and only the sequence $\{y_n\}$ is convergent because $M$ is nonsingular. By definition, $y_n$ satisfies the functional iteration
$$ y_{n+1} = N M^{-1} y_n + f$$
We will know show that this sequence is convergent. Let $H = NM^{-1}$ denote the central matrix. We claim that $\rho(H) < 1$. It is enough to show that $$\rho(H^T) < 1.$$
By assumption, $A^T$ is strictly diagonally dominant by rows and $A^T = M^T - N^T$ is immediate. It follows that the matrix $(M^T)^{-1} N^T$ satisfies $$\rho((M^T)^{-1} N^T) < 1.$$ Howewer $$(M^T)^{-1} N^T = (M^{-1})^T N^T = (N M^{-1})^T = H^T.$$ This shows that $\rho(H) < 1$. It follows that $\{y_n\}$ is convergent and the limit $y$  satisfies $$y = NM^{-1} y + f.$$ It follows that $\{x_n\}$ is convergent with limit $x = M^{-1} y$ that satisfies $$Mx = Nx + f.$$
This completes the analysis.

---

The Jacobi iteration is discussed in here

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2813489/307944